# Limit problem using a Riemann sum: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}+\dots+\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\dots+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

I am trying to find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}+\dots+\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\dots+\sqrt{n}}$$

I believe I should use that

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}n\right)$$

to find the limit, but I am lost. Can anyone help?

Comment: I have edited your question, as without proper formatting it was very hard to parse, but please check if that's what you intended to ask.

Comment: thanks I was trying to find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I believe I should use that
>
> $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}n\right)$$
>   to find the limit, but I am lost. Can anyone help?

**Hint**. One may write, as $n\to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}+\dots+\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\dots+\sqrt{n}}&=\frac{\frac1n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1n}+\sqrt{1+\frac2n}+\dots+\sqrt{1+\frac nn}\right)}{\frac1n\left(\sqrt{\frac1n}+\sqrt{\frac2n}+\dots+\sqrt{\frac nn}\right)}
\\\\&=\frac{\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+\frac{k}n}}{\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}n}}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 8):

If we define $a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n+k}$ and $b_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k}$ we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=2\sqrt{2}-1$$ hence, by [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=\color{red}{2\sqrt{2}-1}.$$